# readline clash with child printf?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, fork, readline

In Linux, readline() in an infinite loop repeatdly reads *text*\n. However, as soon as child processes start printing to the screen, readline no longer *reads* new lines. Even if I repeatdly press enter, readline() doesn't return.

Anyone know what's wrong?

Code sample as requested:

```
char* input;
int cpid;
while(1)
{
     input = readline(">>>");
     strcpy(tempInput, input); //...does some stuff w/ tempInput
     //....
     cpid = fork();
     if(cpid == 0){
           printf("..."); printf("...");
           execl("ls", "ls", "-l", (char*) NULL); //sample execl parameters
     }
     else{
           //do some stuff...
           printf("...");
     }
     free(input);
}

    //readline(">>>") works the first time and doesn't return on subsequent calls
```

The stacktrace of where the code hangs (forever):

```
Thread [1] (Suspended : Signal : SIGINT:Interrupt)  
    __read_nocancel() at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82 0x7ffff78f0490   
    rl_getc() at 0x7ffff7bc3727 
    rl_read_key() at 0x7ffff7bc3c90 
    readline_internal_char() at 0x7ffff7baf25f  
    readline() at 0x7ffff7baf795    
    main() at /home/.../.../xxx.c:95 0x4010a1
```

Edit: This probably sounds like total technobabble to experienced unix developers, but could the child process have somehow 'captured' stdin and fail to release it somehow?

Comment: could you provide a code sample?

Comment: You don't have any calls to `readline` after the fork.

Comment: The child doesn't read anything (just added some code showing an exec call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your child processes, even after exec, still has its standard input connected to your terminal.  Either use `wait()` to wait for the child process to finish, or reopen the child's standard input as `/dev/null`:

```
close(STDIN_FILENO) && open("/dev/null", "O_WRONLY");
```

Answer (score 1):

After you fork(), your child process executes the 2 printf calls, then goes on to execute the while(1)  loop, so what you are doing is creating 1 extra process after every newline.

What you need to do, is kill the child immediately after it prints the 2 ellipses (`...`)

Change your code to this:

```
  if(cpid == 0){
        printf("..."); printf("..."); exec(...); exit(0); 
    }
```

Bear in mind, exit() is called only if the exec() fails.

**Edit:**

If you intend to accept input for some kind of command line interpreter, readline isn't a very good option. Its official man page says:

```
BUGS:

    It’s too big and too slow.
```

I could suggest an alternative way of getting the input string:

```
char c;
inputString = calloc(0,sizeof(char));
inputLength = 0;

c = getchar();
    while(c!='\n')
    {
        inputString = realloc(inputString,(inputLength+1)*sizeof(char));
        inputString[inputLength++] = c;
        c = getchar();
    }
    inputString[inputLength] = '\0';
```

Now you have the string in inputString & its length in inputLength. You could very well do:

```
execlp(inputString,inputString,0);
```

to execute the required functionality.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include a rather crucial exec() call in the child branch. My bad :( The problem at the moment is that the parent's 2nd call to readline() doesn't return.

Comment: Updated w/ the execl call. Tried the exit(0) and it didn't work. According to the specs (I think) exec(...) never returns.

Comment: Maybe, the called process is causing the problem, which executable are you calling?

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code is not working because your call to execl() is failing, therefore the child process will resume at the loop code, which will also be using readline().

You must pass the full path to the executable when using execl(), or use the execlp() variant (which search into PATH environment variable) for it to work.

Even for the simplest syscalls, it's a good practice to always check for their return codes.